# Is there a way to down load a CSV file from a link with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have a urls that when ypu put it on hte browser search bar an click enter it starts dwnloading a CSV file, but using using get in selenium i como to an error. also when I try to clix the export button I get that the button has no click attribute

I cnnot show the URL for security reasons, but I login to my account go to the repor

This is the HTML element
`

```
<a download="Revenues.csv" data-backgrounder="csv_link" class="" href="https://first_part_of_the_link.com/reports/revenues.csv?backgrounder_id=cf5d977a-838c-4cd1-b686"><i class="fa fa-table"></i> Export CSV</a>
```

This is the python code, everything works from login in to getting to the page, but the clic sends en error
`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:/Users/Desktop/test/chromedriver.exe'

driver.get('https://webpage.com/login')
driver.maximize_window()

username =driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div/div/form/p[1]/input")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("serue@gmail.com")

password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div/div/form/p[2]/input")
password.send_keys("assword")
password.submit()

reports_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/header/nav/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[5]/a[1]")
reports_button.click()

revenues_report = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/main/div/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[6]/a")
revenues_report.click()


revenues_download = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"body > header > div.container > div > div.col-lg-auto.pt-2.pt-xl-0.submenu > a:nth-child(1)")
revenues_download.clic()
```

`

The error: AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'clic'

Comment: You are missing a k in `revenues_download.clic()`

Comment: as Luca suggested, fix the typo. another way to check that locator is correct would be open the webpage, go to developer tool--> console, and then try to click with java script like `document.querySelector("a[download='Revenues.csv']").click()` .

Comment: I corrected the typo and I get  **element not interactable** and also the javascript click and it works @simpleApp

Comment: if you don't hate JS, you can perform this action `driver.execute_script("document.querySelector(\"a[download='Revenues.csv']\").click()")` note: \" is to escape "

Comment: I did this and still getting an error, I think is has something to do with href link associated to the button error: [11176:16884:1223/120411.229:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [12:04:11.229] USB:

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your **selenium** actions with **pandas**.

First extract the **url** link, and then use this link to [import the CSV](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) into a dataframe. You can then [export this dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to a location of your choice.

```
import pandas as pd

# insert relevant selenium code here
# ...
revenues_download = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"body > header > div.container > div > div.col-lg-auto.pt-2.pt-xl-0.submenu > a:nth-child(1)")

df = pd.read_csv(revenues_download.get_attribute("href"))
df.to_csv('my_csv.csv', index=False)
```